# Python regex pattern matching digits and parentheses?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I would like to know how I can possibly get/match a list of digist ending with a list of digits in parentheses?

**Original text**

Cisco IOS Software, 3600 Software (C3660-JK9S2-M), Version 12.4(25b)**strong text**, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc1)
ROM: 3600 Software (C3660-JK9S2-M), Version 12.4(25b), RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc1)

**Expected match**

```
12.4(25b)
```

Below is what I tried, but it doesn't work or get the specific version

```
^\d.*\)$ 
^[0-9].*\)$
Version\s\d.*\)
Version \d{2}.*\)$
```

Any idea?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: `.*Version (.*?\)).*`. This expression should work regardless of if the number in the brackets in followed by a letter or not. You then fetch the result (the version number part) by using `\1` as a 'variable'. In python, you do it using the `group()` function from the result. Check beforehand if anything was matched at all for safety.

Full example code:

```
import re

show = 'Cisco IOS Software, 3600 Software (C3660-JK9S2-M), Version 12.4(25b)strong text, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc1) ROM: 3600 Software (C3660-JK9S2-M), Version 12.4(25b), RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc1)'
regexoutput = re.search('.*Version (.*?\)).*', show)

if regexoutput:
    print(regexoutput.group(1))
```

To obtain multiple version numbers (i.e. both instances of the numbers after the 'Version' string, one can use `regexoutput = re.findall('Version (.*?\))',show)`. Here, a list is returned and the group will be automatically fetched by definition (see https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall), so the check at the end is not needed.

Comment: thanks but doesn't filter specific version.. it gets all version output but end with ).

Comment: @searching1 What exactly do you mean? For me, the output looks like this (notice the green part): https://imgur.com/1nnL8tY

Comment: Code: regexoutput = re.search('.*Version (.*?\)).*',show)                                       Output: 'sh ver | i Software\r\nCisco IOS Software, 3600 Software (C3660-JK9S2-M), 12.4(25b), RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc1)\r\nROM: 3600 Software (C3660-JK9S2-M), 12.4(25b), RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc1)\r\nlab.switch01'  Thanks

Comment: @searching1 I updated my answer. As mentioned before, you have to grab the group (which is the result you get inside the brackets I added). A bracket in regex without a preceeding backslash, i.e. `(` instead of `\(`, has a different meaning. Look up the explanation on regex groups to learn more.

Comment: Thanks for your help man.. looks OK now... Will take note of that and I review. More things to learn.. 1 issue has been resolved and twice the issue pops up. :) lol

Comment: Don't forget to accept an answer if it answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

May this working:
`\d+\.\d+\(\d+.\)`
result:
[image]

any problem leave ur comment pls.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs.. Sorry I forgot to mention that there are multiple serial # which like this Version 15.0(1)M, Version 12.4(25b), on thing in common both version end with , comma.

Comment: also what tool are you using to test the regex pattern? is that the built in software in mac?

Comment: So, u want output `Version 15.0(1)M, Version 12.4(25b)` the whole string or just `["15.0(1)", "12.4(25b)"]`？I'm using [VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/) on Mac.

Comment: In my case there are a lot of serial number that I need to pullout. so I just need this for ex. 15.0(1)M & 15.0(1)M.. Thanks

Comment: For this case. you can use `regexoutput = re.findall('Version (.*?\))',show)`

Comment: try`\d+\.\d+\(\d+.?\)`, may be what u want.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Laureal and kushy